# maximuim number of tickers to pass to yahoo when using web.DataReader?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, datareader, pandas-datareader

i am using the below code and i have passed it a request for historical data for up to 200 tickers (ticker_list) - it works with 200 tickers but not 400 tickers. Any ideas on how i could get the data for 400 tickers in the one request? is there a way to maybe have a timer on each of my requests?

```
intquery1 = web.DataReader(ticker_list, 'yahoo', '2013-01-01', '2018-01-20')
```

Comment: I dunno why that happens, but why not just split the list in 2, and then concatenate?  You could also try retrieving from google finance (I dunno if that has a similar limit or not)

Comment: split and concatenate would work but i was wondering if there is a simpler solution.